# Store data on ethereum block chain using react js

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs, react

I'm trying to store data on ethereum blockchain by doing this

```
import storemetadata from "./storemetadata";
```

where i have the smart contract ABI in storemetadata
I now add name like so

```
storemetadata.methods.setName(1, 1, 0, "a", "b", "c").send(
    {
      from: accounts[0]
    },
    (error, transactionHash) => {
      this.setState({ transactionHash });
      console.log(error, "store name on blockchain", transactionHash);
    }
  );
```

now if i get data i get null, However if i use truffle console and do the following i can set and get data

```
SimpleStorage.deployed().then(function(instance) {app =instance})
app.setName(1,1,1,"dfg","yyt","drt")
```

not sure what I am missing. please help

Comment: can you show your `./storemetadata` file contents? to see clearly and guide you.

Comment: @AbdullahAziz: the file is really big here is the link   [link](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js)

Comment: You cannot share file from the remix by sharing the link only. the remix store data locally in your browser. I cannot see with this link. You can take a picture and add in the question.

Comment: Hi there. You could use Drizzle (https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/overview) to abstract away things like this. See the components provided by the project: https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/react/react-components